# Prototypal Inheritance confusion

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I expected this to result in 'woof,' but I'm getting undefined. Clearly not doing something correctly. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
const barker = (state) => {
  return {
    speak: () => console.log(state.sound)
  }
}

const newAnimal = sound => {
  let state = {
    sound
  }
  console.log(state.sound)
  return Object.assign({}, barker(state))
}

console.log(newAnimal("woof").speak())
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with prototypes or inheritance? You're not using either anywhere here.

Comment: `speak` doesn't return anything, just logs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
speak: () => console.log( state.sound )
```

`barker` returns an Object with a function-property `speak` which does not return a value (aka `undefined`). It has the type `() => void` because `console.log` does not return a value.

You can change it to this:

```
speak: () => {
    console.log( state.sound );
    return state.sound;
}
```

Or even just this (without logging):

```
speak: () => state.sound;
```

Comment: …or just drop the `console.log()` around `newAnimal("woof").speak()`

Comment: @Bergi: did you mean to do that *as well as* returning something from `speak`?  Because I think that's the important part.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I meant that either `speak` or its caller should do the logging, but not both. (And when `speak` already logs and the caller doesn't, it's not necessary to return anything, but it wouldn't harm anything either)

Comment: @Bergi Calling `console.log` in `speak` stops it from being a pure-function and introduces side-effects, as well as violating SoC.

Comment: @Dai: violating what?

Comment: @Bergi: ok.  I think the OP expressed the desired behavior by noting the `undefined` result; the logging was already happening... too often.  But maybe I'm reading too much into it.

Comment: @ScottSauyet separation-of-concerns: that a Model (the `barker` object) should not be concerned with its View (the use of `console.log`).

Comment: @Dai: thanks.  Don't know why that abbreviation wasn't coming to me!  ;-)  I certainly agree on all points, although we have no idea if pure functions are even on the OP's radar.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly. It outputs 'woof' 2 times (once from console.log inside newAnimal and once inside speak()). You get undefined because you also output the result of the speak method which is the return value of console.log, which is always undefined.